# How can I do a HTTP PUT with Wget?

Tags: linux, command-line, http, wget

I am trying to use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to access a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) interface, but I can not figure out how to do HTTP PUT with Wget. How can I do it? Or isn't it prossible?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
wget --method=PUT --body-data=<STRING>
```

This is a bit late, but at some point after the original post, they added a "--method" option.
I'm not sure when it was added, but see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684189#24 for details.

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Should be accepted answer in 2014, 2016 or whenever. --method param wasn't avail in wget back in 2010 :(

Comment: Not in busy box

Comment: Seems not working when using with authentication. I tried `wget --method=PUT` with digest access authentication but wget don't performs the authentication procedure like it do with standard GET request.

Comment: --method still not available in centos 7.

Comment: Note only with GNU wget, not busybox wget.

Comment: Can also do `wget --method=PUT --body-file=<FILENAME>` if your body is a file.

Answer (score 26):

Wget can't do PUT. Use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) instead, with `-T`.

Comment: there's also a [wput utility](http://wput.sourceforge.net/) tho it seems limited to FTP.

Comment: Wget can now do PUT using --method.

Answer (score 22):

Since this is [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) interface, I think you'd want to use `curl` with `-X PUT`, like this:

```
curl -i -X PUT http://www.example.tld/rest/updateEntity/1234?active=false
```

Or if you need to "post" data from a file, like an XML:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8" -d @"/tmp/some-file.xml" http://www.example.tld/rest/updateEntity
```

Answer (score 6):

For me following worked:

```
curl -T <file-path> <url>
```

For some reason when I did following it nothing happened (no error as well):

```
curl -X PUT -d <file-path> <url>         (did not work)
```

Comment: `-d` will send the data you entered on the command line, so it will try to PUT file path as text.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a file as data, you can do the following.

```
curl -X PUT -d "something=blabla&somethingelse=blaha" http://www.example.com
```